# MFC Functions from :: namespace?

Tags: c++, mfc, namespaces

I started using MFC a while ago and I came across functions or rather methods, that are called with "::" before name of the functions. What is it?

For example:

```
::SendMessage()
```

What is that scope? How can I define one if I wanted to?

Thanks

Comment: Global scope methods are called that way.

Comment: Usually the `::` global scope is omitted, but may be necessary to disambiguate the same identifier in different namespaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::` before a function name specifies to use that function from the **global namespace** rather than a member function of a particular class. This, as you have found, is used extensively in the `MFC` headers/source.

The reason is actually quite simple. Let's consider the `CWnd` class, which has a `SendMessage` member function with the following signature:

```cpp
class CWnd : public CObject {
//...
    LRESULT SendMessage(UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
//...
}
```

The *implementation* of this function can simply pass control to the non-MFC, global WinAPI function with the same name. But this has a different signature:

```cpp
LRESULT SendMessage(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

So, when the *member function* calls this non-MFC object, with the first argument being its 'own' `HWND` object, the `::` prefix is used to make it clear to any future coders that a non-MFC function is being called:

```cpp
LRESULT CWnd::SendMessage(UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return ::SendMessage(m_hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam); // Clarifies that we're using a non-class function.
}
```

Feel free to ask for further explanation and/or clarification.

Comment: Using a fully qualified name is not required here. There is no risk of a recursive call. The class member has a different signature, so it's discarded as a candidate during [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). [Unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) will find names in global namespace.

Comment: @IInspectable Indeed, yet the MFC source does use the *explicit* global namespace prefix. Makes things much clearer, I feel. (Post edited for correctness!)

Comment: Personally, I would *always* be explicit. Using a fully qualified name more directly expresses the intent, reduces mental load for readers, and safeguards against future changes, that might introduce names that would eventually collide. It's just not *"required"*.

Comment: And how would I define global namespace for myself? Like if I wanted to add method to global namespace, or creating Empty project, where would I start ?

Comment: @ligazetom To add to the global namespace, just define a global function - that is, a function that isn't in any other namespace or class, like a good, old-fashioned `extern int MyFunction(int arg);` on its own, somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

`::` is refering to the *global* namespace.

Answer (score 2):

`::SendMessage()` denotes a method, that is available in the global namespace. It is not bound to the scope of any class in particular.